# For loop and array in bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

Trying to output part of bash array

```
ARRAY=(1,2,3,4,5)
for((i=0;i<3;i++))do
    echo "${ARRAY[$i]}"
done
```

but in first loop echo output full array, and in the following loops output empty lines.
  How i can output array by elements in !this for cycle

Comment: Your array has one element, the string `1,2,3,4,5`, not 5 separate elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ array=(1 2 3 4 5); for((i=0;i<3;i++)) do echo "${array[i]}"; done

1
2
3
```

space is the delimiter.  Also, be careful using all uppercase identifiers, you may end up overwriting `bash` variables.